# How to remove Login button from layout page after user login

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on MVC application in Visual Studio 2012. On my layout page, I have a button for login. I want to remove my login page button from my layout page, after the user login. I'm trying to do this in the following way, but it's not working. Tell me how to figure this out. Is my way of doing this correct?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var login = 0;

     $('#login-request').on('click', function () {
        var name = $("#lg-name").val();
        var pwd = $("#lg-password").val();

        if (name.toString() == "" || pwd.toString() == "")            
            alert("one of the fields is incorrect or missing");
        else
            login = 1;

    });

    $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#layout', function () {
        if (login == 1) {//login condition
            $('#login').remove();
        }
    });
});
```

This is my layout page

```
<head>
     <title>PetZone</title>
</head>

<body id="layout">
     <header class="page-header" id="header-page">
     <div class="row" id ="headre-row">

     <div class="col-md-2">

          <div class="btn-group">
                <a class="btn" id="login" href="#" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("login")'">LOGIN <span class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span></a>                
                <a class="btn" id="signup" href="#" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("signup")'">SIGNUP <span class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-sign-up"></span></a>                
            </div>
        </div>

     </div>

    </header>
</body>
```

Comment: is it `#login-request` or `#login`?????

Comment: can you post your html as well? Without seeing your html, if you are not doing post-back, you would need to remove/hide your `#login` container in the `#login-request` click event instead of page load.

Comment: I have added my HTML.

Comment: where is your `#login-request`? is it in a different page? If `#login-request` and `#login` buttons are in a different page, you would need to set up global variable, local storage or session variable for your `login==1` since your local variable can not be used from another page.

Answer (score 1):

Consider replacing selectors with simple call:

```
if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {
   //hide link or set it to Logout action
else
   //show Logon link
}
```